# textView not showing on first change

Tags: android, textview, pause

1. my_text.setText("Dave");

//Small pause...

```
    try {  
         Thread.sleep(1000);  
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {  
          e.printStackTrace();  
    }

 my_text.setText("Bob");
```

I want to change my textView, pause 1 second, then change it again. When I run the program, it doesn't refresh after first change. It just shows the second change after returning. How can I force the refresh on the first change to the textview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use `Handler` like below code

```
my_text.setText("Dave");
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    my_text.setText("Bob");
                }
            });
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: That works, however, what if I have 20 'Name Changes' in a row. Is there a way to do this without 20 of these nested loops? For example, what if I have an array of 20 names called 'name_list', and I want to show them all in order and with 1 second between each?

Answer (score 0):

Try below **for the edited question**

Keep your all 20 names in any collection array or list.

```
int position = 0;
String names [] = {"0","1","20"};
Handler handler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        my_text.setText(names[position++]);
        if (position < names.length) {
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    }
};
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
```